# How to get the block diagram between the inductor current and the output current in a closed-loop buck circuit?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, transfer-function

The block diagram below describes the relation between the perturbation of reference voltage **vref(s)** and the output voltage **v(s)**. Using this block diagram, I could derive the closed-loop transfer function from **vref(s)** to **v(s)**.
[image]

But now I want to get the closed-loop transfer function from output current **io(s)** to inductor current **iL(s)**  (I want to know the ability of the inductor current to track the load current) What should I do to modify this block diagram to get the transfer function? Or could anyone derive  the transfer function not using the block diagram?

Comment: Normally we assume that out load current variations are handled by the output bulk capacitor and these have minimal effects on inductor current so, what are you trying to achieve and, for more realistic purposes, why can't you use a simulator?

Comment: You don't give a circuit so it's impossible to say, but usually the inductor is the only DC path for current from the switch(s) to the load, and there is no significant DC path to ground (just the capacitors, which block DC current).  So the _average_ load current _must_ equal the average inductor current, and visa-versa.  Finding the transfer function for that is a matter of circuit analysis or, as @Andyaka suggests, simulation.

Comment: This is a voltage-mode control converter that is illustrated by the block diagram. There is no current loop per se. If you want to understand how the current loop operates in a current-mode-controlled converter, you can read this [article](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/2101/articles/H2PToday2101_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) that I published a while back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking up some references, I think I figure it out.I post my answer here and hope it will help you too. If there are errors, please point out! Thanks!

I draw a block diagram of Buck circuit like this:
[image]

Here for simplicity, I ignore the perturbation of input voltage (partly because I don't need it) and I only consider the perturbation of reference voltage and load current. Also I let the sensor gain H be equal to 1.
So I derive a closed-loop transfer function from load current to inductance current:
$$ Giic(s)=\frac{Zout}{1+Gc·Gdv}·Gc·Gdi-Gii$$
where

**Gii** is the transfer function from small signal **iload** to small signal **iL** in open-loop;

**Zout** is the transfer function of output impendence;

**Gdv** is the transfer function from small signal **d** to small signal **vo**;

**Gdi** is the transfer function from small signal **d** to small signal **iL**;

**Gdi** is the transfer function of compensator;

You could derive these transfer function through small-signal equivalent circuit model of Buck circuit, which could be found easily, so I don't list them here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your block diagram, Zout must be connected from the converter's output to ground as the load current directly influences the output voltage via that impedance. This makes computing the inductor current rather simple.

Compute the transfer function from iload(s) to v(s): **v(s) = Zi(s) * iload(s)**. (You have to find Zi.) This gives you the output voltage variation caused by a certain load current variation. Note that you have to take the entire feedback loop into account when calculating this. You can assume vref(s)=0 for this calculation. (Also note that Zi should be a negative pure resistance for a DC current. You can use this fact to verify that you didn't get a sign wrong somewhere.)

Once you have this transfer function Zi, you can calculate the inductor current: iL(s) = v(s) / Zout + iload(s) = Zi(s) * iload(s) / Zout + iload(s) = **iload(s) * (1 + Zi(s) / Zout(s))**.

The reasoning behind this is the following: All current that's output by the converter flows through the inductor. Zout is in parallel to the load. Therefore, the currents flowing through Zout and the load add up and equal the inductor current, which gives us the last formula directly.